# A doubt regarding Cauchy's theorem and analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $f$ be analytic on $\mathbb{H}$ and continuous and bounded on $\overline{\mathbb{H}}.$ Let $R$ be a closed rectangle in $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ such that one side of $R$ falls on the real line $\mathbb{R}.$

1. Is it still true that $$\int_R f(z)dz=0?$$
2. Can we make a domain $\mathcal{D}\supset \mathbb{H},$ which also contains $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is analytic on $\mathcal{D}?$

NB: $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \Im{z}>0\}$

Comment: first is true by the usual integration theorems (eg dominated convergence applied to $0=\int_Rf(z+i\epsilon)dz \to \int_R f(z)dz=0$) and second is not true as one can construct examples where $f$ is even infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb R$ in the real sense (and of course $f'(x+i\epsilon) \to f'(x)$ and the like for all $x \in \mathbb R)$  and still fails to extend analytically into the lower half plane at any point on the real line  (such examples are easy to construct on the unit disc and be carried with the appropriate Mobius transform to the upper half-plane)